# PHP Changing the array outside of if-statement

Tags: php

```
$GROUP_ID = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

if ($_GET) {
    $a = $_GET['id'];
    $GROUP_ID = array($a); // 10
}
```

So yeah, this code doesn't work. I've tried push but i need to completely replace the array, and they array cannot be empty at the start. Any insights on this please?

Comment: What is the intention of your code? What do you want as output?

Comment: How does this "not work"?  What's it supposed to do?  What is it supposed to output?  What does it output?

Comment: I just want to change the value of the $GROUP_ID array, since there is a foreach loop that relies on the current value of $GROUP_ID array.

Comment: If you're trying to check if `$_GET['id']` exists, you have to use [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: @RocketHazmat - Sir, it doesn't change the array. Example the GET request will set the $a to 10. The array should be $GROUP_ID = array(10). But it's not.

Comment: @user2062950: `$_GET` will *always* exist, regardless of if you send it a query string or not.  He needs to check if `$_GET['id']` exists using `isset`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat good point, amended my comment

Comment: @user2726071: So, what is it then?  What *does* `var_dump($_GET['id']);` show?  How about `echo $a;`, what does that show?  How do you know this code isn't working?

Comment: with this code, the $GROUP_ID that is declared above the If-Statement is the one that is running the foreach loop. I will try the answers now. But do i need to use if($GET['id']) ?

Comment: @ArmanJonVillalobos: You should use `if(isset($_GET['id']))`

Comment: Also note that I'm using ajax to pass the id variable.

Comment: @ArmanJonVillalobos: Make sure you're using `GET`, not `POST`.

Comment: Yes sir, I can output the value being sent via GET. if i say, echo $_GET['id'] then put an alert(msg) on ajax, it returns the value being sent.

Comment: @ArmanJonVillalobos: Are you sure that it's getting into your `if` block?  Put an `echo` inside the block to see if it's getting there.

Comment: @RocketHazmat `$_GET` will evaluate to `false` if there are no get args.

Comment: @Izkata: True, but what if he forgot to send an `id` key?  What if he sent `value=10`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put the value of $a into your array use:

```
$GROUP_ID[] = $a;
```

This can be seen on [the php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) which show:

```
<?php
// Create a simple array.
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
print_r($array);

// Now delete every item, but leave the array itself intact:
foreach ($array as $i => $value) {
    unset($array[$i]);
}
print_r($array);

// Append an item (note that the new key is 5, instead of 0).
$array[] = 6;
print_r($array);

// Re-index:
$array = array_values($array);
$array[] = 7;
print_r($array);
?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
    [5] => 6
)
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [1] => 7
)
```

You see how the append works

Comment: I'm sorry but it's still not working. The value of the array is still not changing.

Answer (score 0):

To append to the array

```
$GROUP_ID[] = $a;
```

But, since you want a whole new array, this would work. Of course this would overwrite the old one, so if you want to keep the old one, don't assign it to `$GROUP_ID`

```
$GROUP_ID = array_merge($GROUP_ID, array($a));
```

Comment: The asker specifically says "I need to completely replace the array".  Your answer does not do that.

Comment: That would append `$a` to the array, he said "i need to completely replace the array".

Comment: Yeah, saw that... fixing answer.

Answer (score -1):

It should be working:

```
$GROUP_ID = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

if ($_GET) {
    $a = $_GET['id'];
    $GROUP_ID = array($a); // 10
} 

var_dump($GROUP_ID);
```

If I request `index.php?id=v`, I get:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "v" }
```

Comment: The process that relies on $GROUP_ID is 

foreach($GROUP_ID as $id=>$team_id) {
 $TEAMS_ARR[$team_id][] = $org->get_list($team_id);
}

Comment: @ArmanJonVillalobos That doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question or this answer...  Is it `$TEAMS_ARR` that's not changing?

Comment: I mean, the array is not changing.